# gridExtra::marrangegrob() disregards ggbreak::scale_y_break()

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, ggbreak

I'm creating multiple `ggplot2` plots with a "broken" Y axis using `ggbreak::scale_y_break`, and exporting these to a single PDF document using `gridExtra::marrangegrob()` and `ggsave()`. It turns out that when saving, the broken Y axis is in fact ignored. Here is some synthetic sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
suppressMessages(library(ggbreak))
library(gridExtra)

d <- tibble(val = c(rep(1, 10000), rep(2, 100), rep(3, 50)))

plt <- d |> ggplot(mapping = aes(x = val)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 3, color = "white") + theme_light() + 
    scale_y_break(breaks = c(150, 9950))

plt

plts <- list(plt, plt)
ggsave(filename = "test.pdf", plot = marrangeGrob(grobs = plts, nrow = 1, ncol = 1))
```

The plot `plt` looks as follows:

[image]

In the PDF, however, it looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug, and if so, in which of the involved packages? Thanks!